# How to automate the deployment of new versions of a PHP script running in the background without downtime?

Tags: php, bash, rabbitmq, amqp, php-deployer

I have a AMQP consumer (a RabbitMQ consumer) written in PHP **always active running in the background**. This script is run in multiple nodes and 12 times per node: 12 unix background processes running:

`php -f consumer.php &`.

If a new version of the code must be deployed, at the moment I always have to kill ALL these processes manually and launch them again one by one, in each node.

1. Is there a way to automate the deployment of background scripts? I.e. put it in a deployment pipeline and then having them reloaded, similarly to using https://deployer.org.
2. Is there a way to avoid downtime?
3. Any way ReactPHP would help in this case?

Comment: Consider https://github.com/shaneharter/PHP-Daemon specifically `SIGHUP kill -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#supervisor-configuration) (the solution works for any always running background process, not just PHP and Laravel). [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/running.html)!

> Configuring Supervisor
>
> Supervisor configuration files are typically stored in the /etc/supervisor/conf.d directory. Within this directory, you may create any number of configuration files that instruct supervisor how your processes should be monitored. For example, let's create a laravel-worker.conf file that starts and monitors a queue:work process:
>
> Starting Supervisor
>
> Once the configuration file has been created, you may update the Supervisor configuration and start the processes using the following commands:
>
> sudo supervisorctl reread
>
> sudo supervisorctl update
>
> sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*

It will even help me starting as many processes I want with a single configuration file and single command. Again, from the Laravel docs:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
```

By calling `sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*`, 8 background processes will run, which also restart in case of error.

If I just want to restart with a new released version, I call the `restart` command directly:

`supervisorctl restart laravel-worker:*`

I'll just integrate this as a Deployer task in my CI/CD pipeline.